# Media files from database into OBIEE

Tags: oracle, image, business-intelligence, obiee

Does OBIEE support importing media files like photos that are stored in particular format in database tables?

For example if you are making an analysis with a client info and want to add client's picture to it, how is this possible in OBIEE? Does Admin tool work with them? Couldn't find useful info on this in the web, maybe someone here faced this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with rtf template. If the data is comming from BLOB column in a table then after inserting the element in the form field you just have to update advanced part of property box to:

```xml
<fo:instream-foreign-object content-type="image/jpg">
<xsl:value-of select="YOUR_IMAGE_COLUMN_NAME"/>
</fo:instream-foreign-object>
```

The same way you could insert different content-types (MIME).
More here: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/bip/BIPRD/GUID-58D7E662-146A-44AA-86F9-111E2C6DB3A5.htm#BIPRD2396 Regards...